# How to support RTL and LTR in sass

Tags: css, sass, right-to-left

What would be the best way to implement RTL support in Sass?

I don't like to override css properties and I don't like to add multiple css files (e.g `styles.css` + `styles-rtl.css`)

Can you suggest any better way?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use [postcss](https://postcss.org/) in your project you could use this [postcss plugin](https://github.com/elchininet/postcss-rtlcss).

Comment: Try https://www.sitelint.com/blog/sass-and-rtl-ltr-support-how-to-make-your-website-multilingual/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. [Handle it using sass mixins](https://gist.github.com/saeedseyfi/4eb9f4634d5eb053da05375c59092da8)

   - pros:

     1. Smaller output file in comparison to method #2
     2. You'll have a semantic sass because of using `rtl` and `ltr` mixins
   - cons:

     1. You can't support both `rtl` and `ltr` both in a single output file
2. [Handle it using `dir` attr of `html` tag](https://gist.github.com/saeedseyfi/368c339ecacc6d3d251d3ef13ffe2bc7)

   - pros:

     1. You don't need to compile your sass file twice (you can support `rtl` and `ltr` in a single file)
   - cons:

     1. Your output file might get heavy because of long `css` rules
3. [Handle it using `sass` vars](https://www.sitepoint.com/manage-rtl-css-sass-grunt/)

   - pros:

     1. Smaller output file in comparison to method #2
     2. Smaller sass files in comparison to method #1
   - cons:

     1. You can't support both `rtl` and `ltr` both in a single output file
     2. Your `sass` files are not very semantic like method #1

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at using `postcss-rtl` for `postcss`

https://github.com/vkalinichev/postcss-rtl
https://postcss.org/